# JS: window.open opens a window outside of my screen

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code to open a popup window in JS. in was working perfect until I connected my laptop to a projection. Then whenever I tried to run the code it opens the window outside of my screen. And when I resize the down border of the window then it comes to my screen and is possible to see whole the new window.

It is interesting that I tried to use `left` and `top` but it is not 100% useful. Also I played with resolution of my machine but it is not helpful also.

Here is the code:

```
var oWindow = window.open(sURL, "_blank", "left=0,top=o,menubar=0,resizable=0,status=1,fullscreen=1,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0", true);
```

[image: The windows is look like this. It does not show the toolbar, and when I resize the page it shows.]

What is the source of the problem?

Comment: "What is the source of the problem?" — Probably your desktop's window management algorithms

Comment: It's definitely not a JavaScript problem.

Comment: Seeing the actual code that opens the window would be helpful in case it is a problem with the code... but as the other comments have noted, it is probably some weird interaction with the window manager being confused by the projector.

Comment: I added the code and picture. I want the first pixel of the window is set on (0,0) but it somewhere in the negative numbers.

Comment: `somewhere in the negative numbers` ... what do you mean? how do you know its set to negative numbers?

Comment: @VivekAthalye If you know computer graphics there are 2 axes X  and Y which they continue to the outside of the screen and they considered as negative numbers. The point at most left top of your screen is (0,0), inside of the screen to the direction of most right down point is positive and the opposite direction is negative.

Comment: @Martin :) ... I know what X, Y coordinates are and left top of your screen being (0,0). My point was: have you verified that your new window's left/top is set to negative values? Looking at the image that you have attached, its not clear where your new window is.

Comment: @VivekAthalye Yes the most left top point of the window is somewhere is (-1500,-500) when I set left to 1500 and top to 500 then the most left top point of the new window will come to visible.